# How do I fix partition after messing up during install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I've been dabbling in linux for over 20 years but i'm just a user. I got a new laptop (10 year old Lenovo) and started a new install and the partition thing tripped me up. So it's not dual boot and now Windows is broken. It comes up and goes into a repair mode but it won't repair.

Following an install tutorial, In Win10 i opened DISKMNGMT and shrunk the drive, creating a space for linux. THen began install from a thumb drive.

I have never understood the partition section of the install but in the past iv'e always made it work. But with Ubuntu 20.04 it seemed less intuitive. apparently i screwed that part up. So, i'm looking for a good tutorial to help me get the partition back where it was and hopefully restore windows (i need it for work) or perhaps there is a better partition utility that i can install over the thumb drive ?

Now i have Ubuntu running of the thumb drive and i can Gpaprted is a lot more intuitive but i still don't know what to do the partitions to get windoze to resume as well as installing Ubuntu-  I sure do miss Wubi.

thanks

Comment: If 10 year old system, then it is BIOS with MBR partitioning & 4 primary partition limit. If newer then UEFI with gpt partitioning. Ubuntu only needs one partition which can be primary or logical (inside extended partition). No need for swap partition anymore as it uses swap file. Post this: `sudo parted -l` in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think everything's all right, just plug into the live usb , disable secure boot (if u don't know how , search google for "how to disable secure boot in lenovo) then after booting into usb , choose the option to install ubuntu alongside other operating systems. Just create a 50-60 gb free space, make 2 partitons as follows -
1)set space to 512 mb , choose use as (mount point) to boot(this is for bootloader)
imp** this is necessary for u to choose where to install the bootloader (it will be a big dropbox at the bottom ) choose the name of ur hardrive(always the top one if u have a single hard drive) dont choose other partitions as this may mess you up !
2)choose  all remaining free space and format it to ext4 and mount as "/" (root)

This will simply  install ubuntu alongside windows and you can fix other messed up parts later. [and ubuntu's bootloader(grub) will override windows bootloader (efi boot manager) this way u will be able to boot into windows using grub.]

if this doesn't work,please further describe your problem.